# Program goes funny when letter + space + letter is entered

Tags: java

when I enter the value "Adam J" for my first name, the following is outputted:

```
Please enter student first name: Adam J
Please enter student surname: Please select Subject Unit:
```

I would like it to reject this value, like it would if a number was entered. Ideally, I don't want it to accept it if it has a space in it so It would say "Please Enter A Valid First Name".

```
 case 1:
                System.out.print("Please enter student first name: ");
                firstName = scan.next(); 

                while(!firstName.matches("[-a-zA-Z]*"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Please enter a valid first name: ");
                    firstName = scan.next(); 
                }
                firstCap = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1);

    System.out.print("Please enter student surname: ");
        lastName = scan.next();

        while(!lastName.matches("[-a-zA-Z]*"))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid surname: ");
            lastName = scan.next();
        }
        surCap = lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastName.substring(1);

        System.out.print("Please select Subject Unit: "); 
        unit = scan.next();
```

I am confused as to why: "Please enter student surname: Please select Subject Unit:" are on the same line as well.

Can you help? 
Thanks

Comment: Your names can contain `-` character also.. I hope its a feature..

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct so that it can help others.

Comment: @Ramesh-X leaving - in for double-barrelled names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `next()` method retrieves the next token from the stream, which by default is delimited by whitespace.  The call to `next()` for the first name only consumes `Adam`.  The next call to `next()` consumes `J`, leaving you at the third prompt.

You should call `nextLine()` instead, to retrieve the entire line, so that `Adam J` is consumed all at once for `firstName`.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter student first name: ");
                firstName = scan.nextLine(); 

                while(!firstName.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid first name: ");
                    firstName = scan.nextLine(); 
                }
                firstCap = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1);

    System.out.println("Please enter student surname: ");
        lastName = scan.nextLine();

        while(!lastName.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid surname: ");
            lastName = scan.nextLine();
        }
        surCap = lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastName.substring(1);

        System.out.println("Please select Subject Unit: "); 
        unit = scan.nextLine();
```

I am assuming the extra - in your regex was unintended. Also, your regex should be checking [a-zA-Z]+ rather than [a-zA-Z]* as an empty name doesn't seem valid to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.